# Get rid of overhang beyond masking border in ggmap?

Tags: raster, r, sf, masking, ggmap

I built a terrain map of Nevada and plot the state border around it. The resulting map has a buffer-like overhang across the state border which I used to mask the raster. How can I get rid of the overhanging data? The code below makes this example easily reproducible.

```
    library(ggmap)
    library(raster)
    library(sf)
    library(ggplot)
    library(USAboundaries)
    state <- us_states(states = c("Nevada"))
    map3 <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon=-116.888369, lat=39.509636), zoom = 4, maptype = "terrain", color= "color",
                          style = "feature:road|visibility:off&style=feature:administrative|element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:administrative|element:geometry|visibility:off&style=feature:landscape|visibility:on|saturation:-100|lightness:-10&style=feature:landscape|element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:poi|visibility:off&style=feature:transit|visibility:off") 
    map.rast <- ggmap_rast(map = map3)
    map.only <- mask(map.rast, state) 
    basemap.df <- data.frame(rasterToPoints(map.only))
    
    ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data= basemap.df, aes(x=x, y=y,col=rgb(layer.1/255, layer.2/255, layer.3/255))) + 
      scale_color_identity() +
      geom_sf(data=state, color= "black", fill=NA, size=0.3, inherit.aes = F) +
      coord_sf()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The expansion is done because of the `coord_sf()` parameter `expand = TRUE`.
Setting it to `FALSE` should remove the "buffer".
Here's the corresponding part of the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html).

```
ggplot() + 
      geom_point(data= basemap.df, aes(x=x, y=y,col=rgb(layer.1/255, layer.2/255, layer.3/255))) + 
      scale_color_identity() +
      geom_sf(data=state, color= "black", fill=NA, size=0.3, inherit.aes = F) +
      coord_sf(expand = F)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works for the some sides but not the diagonal/bottom portion. Any idea how to crop that out within the code?